# Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: spring-boot, macos, intellij-idea

I am using MacOS Catalina and Intellij 2021.2.2 community Edition.  When ever I try to start my Java application, I am getting below error. I tried to change the Java versions but no help. Please help?

````
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.net.NetworkInterface.init()V
    at java.base/java.net.NetworkInterface.init(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.NetworkInterface.<clinit>(NetworkInterface.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils.findFirstNonLoopbackAddress(InetUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils.findFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(InetUtils.java:64)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.getFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:51)```
````

Comment: Seems a dependency with "java.net.NetworkInterface.init" class is not added to the classpath. Share a sample project, so I can provide you with steps to fix

Comment: did you solve this? having the same issue..